# Android Studio 2.0 preview 6 gradle 2.0.0-alpha6 BootstrapApplication class not found for maps.jar

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.0

When I upgraded from Android Studio 2 preview 4 to preview 6, my app builds, but it crashes immediately when launched on a device.  My app uses google maps and play services and was building successfully before the upgrade.

Disabling instant run allows me to build and not crash, however there's no point to using Studio 2.0 beta if instant run is disabled.

I tried going back to Preview 4, and the problem persisted.  It appears the root of the problem lies somewhere with using

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'
```

When I force it to use alpha3 (my previous working setup) everything is fine and instant run works as expected with studio preview 4 and 6:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'
```

The exception when the app launches/crashes is:

> 01-21 17:35:31.555 30075-30075/com.company.myappnameplus
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process:
>   com.company.myappnameplus, PID: 30075 java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to instantiate application
>   com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar",
>   zip file "/data/app/com.company.myappnameplus-1/base.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/com.company.myappnameplus-1/split_lib_dependencies_8b36bf2fb6c9fc3dcd915b0effe791e5a50faf8d.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.company.myappnameplus-1/split_lib_slice_0_1a0168c89c1a86b61600aa66f7d6f319881b77c4.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.company.myappnameplus-1/split_lib_slice_1_a471c1e8faba5d17663780e37b7f227a45f3bc48.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.company.myappnameplus-1/split_lib_slice_2_9dc8d6131a401b2484dca13c95c2bfff6ce9fe24.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.company.myappnameplus-1/split_lib_slice_3_489c8b6bf579c4a0b5a7968fa43d579b9fbf0ea1.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.company.myappnameplus-1/split_lib_slice_4_0e650edd3ae479f251ae5a4b5a1bf84498771472.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.company.myappnameplus-1/split_lib_slice_5_95fd91377416b71171b9b62c4c6559534d10668d.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.company.myappnameplus-1/split_lib_slice_6_a24f63d8736d4696a2261fd6310aca5decd2e753.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.company.myappnameplus-1/split_lib_slice_7_bc927a3c249d78a3bed63d615fee2368a584d167.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.company.myappnameplus-1/split_lib_slice_8_3930d0a866d3a4c4384dc1c0b3d6baa5c310bed1.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.company.myappnameplus-1/split_lib_slice_9_20ea2f37b2bb23f478a650eb82cd0465187969d4.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.company.myappnameplus-1/lib/arm64,
>   /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]] at
>   android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:578) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4680)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) Caused
>   by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar",
>   zip file "/data/app/com.company.myappnameplus-1/base.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/com.company.myappnameplus-1/split_lib_dependencies_8b36bf2fb6c9fc3dcd915b0effe791e5a50faf8d.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.company.myappnameplus-1/split_lib_slice_0_1a0168c89c1a86b61600aa66f7d6f319881b77c4.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.company.myappnameplus-1/split_lib_slice_1_a471c1e8faba5d17663780e37b7f227a45f3bc48.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.company.myappnameplus-1/split_lib_slice_2_9dc8d6131a401b2484dca13c95c2bfff6ce9fe24.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.company.myappnameplus-1/split_lib_slice_3_489c8b6bf579c4a0b5a7968fa43d579b9fbf0ea1.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.company.myappnameplus-1/split_lib_slice_4_0e650edd3ae479f251ae5a4b5a1bf84498771472.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.company.myappnameplus-1/split_lib_slice_5_95fd91377416b71171b9b62c4c6559534d10668d.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.company.myappnameplus-1/split_lib_slice_6_a24f63d8736d4696a2261fd6310aca5decd2e753.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.company.myappnameplus-1/split_lib_slice_7_bc927a3c249d78a3bed63d615fee2368a584d167.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.company.myappnameplus-1/split_lib_slice_8_3930d0a866d3a4c4384dc1c0b3d6baa5c310bed1.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.company.myappnameplus-1/split_lib_slice_9_20ea2f37b2bb23f478a650eb82cd0465187969d4.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.company.myappnameplus-1/lib/arm64,
>   /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]

Does anyone know what's going on or how to overcome this error?

Comment: What do you expect, its a preview and not production ready yet. See if you can send some feedback  to Google (Android Developers) which will help them iron out such bugs in the AS 2 preview code

Comment: @Tasos I understand that - however, since I've been using preview 4 successfully for over a month and this upgrade broke my ability to use instant run, just looking for a quick fix.  If anything, someone else who encounters this issue will hit this page and offer tips/suggestions.

Comment: There's a bugs page, not sure this fix is related to the instant run your talking about -- i had a look around for you about when preview 7 is comming out but i didnt find anything. should be soon i think  -- http://tools.android.com/knownissues#TOC-Some-test-run-configurations-don-t-work

Comment: another thing is you jumped form 4 to 6 and 6 was a 3mb patch update -- http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio20preview6available. 5 is 16meg update. Did you update AS with the 5 update --- http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio20preview5available -- maybe thats what screwed up the instant run -- you may need to unistall AS and get the full 6 that includes 5 updates -- you can get it here -- http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest

Comment: there you go -- about 40mins ago google released 7 -- http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio20preview7available  -- http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest -- give that a go but i suggest reinstalling if you missed the 5 update

Comment: @Tasos thanks, I'll give 7 a try!  I ended up getting preview 6 to work, but I had to downgrade gradle to 2.0.0-beta3 instead of beta6.  I'll report back about preview 7.

Comment: should be ok with a gen public preview realease

Comment: @Tasos preview 7 was even worse than preview 6.  I did a full install (just like I did with 6, not using the patches) and Studio would get GC out of memory any time you'd try to build.  Heap is already at 4g.  Tried 6g, no luck.  Went back to preview 4 so I can continue working.  I won't be trying any new previews until 2.0 is RC, so much wasted time.